# Forced RTL Layout option not showing up on my Huawei phone

Tags: huawei, developer-options

I have a Huawei phone. When I searched the "Forced RTL Layout" option, it shows up. When I click on it, it leads me to the top of Developer Options. But nowhere on the list do I see the Force RTL option.

[image]

This is very frustrating and I can't seem to find anyone talking about it online. My old phone was also a Huawei and the same problem happens. Both my parents have Huawei phones and neither of them has the option either.

How can I get the Force RTL option out and apply it?

Answer (score 0):

RTL Layout and Huawei... I don't think you can change the layout yourself unless you're a software developer. Well yes, this is a software issue;

I talked to a salesperson from Huawei and he told me that it should be possible to integrate this option with a software update. He promised to tell the people who are developing Huawei software about RTL layout.